# How to separate jquery response from $.post?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

jquery $.post:

```
$.post(
    'includes/studiesAjax/addTryb.php',
    {inputVL: inputVL},
    function(res){
        $("#container").html(res);
    }
);
```

response is long html code

I would like to extract data from the first line of response beetween `<p>` tag, separate it from response and assign to new variable. How to do it?

Comment: I don't follow; can you clarify your intention?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to return a more structured repsonse (like JSON, or at least only that part you need) so you don't need to post-process?

Answer (score 3):

```
function(res){
    var newVar = $(res).find('p:first').html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should transform the response to a jquery object and then you can act on as usual:

```
$.post(
            'includes/studiesAjax/addTryb.php',
            {inputVL: inputVL},
            function(res){
                var result = $(res).find('p:first').html();
                $("#container").html(result );
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return json instead html you can do like this.

```
       $.post(
            'includes/studiesAjax/addTryb.php',
            {inputVL: inputVL},
            function(res){
                var data = JSON.parse(res);
                if(data && data.response1){
                    result = (data.response1);
                    console.log(result);
                }
                if(data && data.response2)
                    $("#container").html(data.response2);
            }
        );
```